# Azure Data Factory Pagination for RFC 5988 compliant REST API (Meraki)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, meraki-api

I'm trying to implement Azure Data Factory's Copy Activity to copy data from an API to our SQL Data Warehouse. I have set up the source & sinks correctly so that when I trigger the pipeline it pulls and loads the first load of data but I am struggling with pagination.

The API I am trying to pull data from is Cisco Meraki (https://developer.cisco.com/meraki/api-v1/#!introduction/meraki-dashboard-api) which is a REST API that uses the RFC 5988 pagination method. This means it passes the pagination rules for the next page in a response header.

I run the following API call

```
{{baseUrl}}/networks/:networkId/events?productType=wireless&perPage=1000
```

which passes the following as a link header response to dictate the next page

```
<{{baseUrl}}/networks/:networkId/events?endingBefore=2021-10-19T13%3A03%3A06.769680Z&perPage=1000&productType=wireless>; rel=prev, <{{baseUrl}}/networks/:networkId/events?perPage=1000&productType=wireless&startingAfter=2021-10-19T13%3A44%3A01.586776Z>; rel=next
```

How can I implement the above in the pagination rules in ADF to get the next page of info? I've currently defined the rules as here:
[ADF Pagination Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmFSx.png) but it's not accessing any new information. No error message just still only the first page.

Thanks for any pointers,

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is a bit old, but I thought I would comment for others.

I have found that when processing a response that conforms to , datafactory will process the pagination if you do nothing. i.e. leave the pagination rules empty. This will then add `"paginationRules": {"supportRFC5988": "true"}` to the source Json.

I have tested this and verified it reads all pages.